# sorting in core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I use the following code to get list of nstrings

I want to sort them out alphabetically

how to do thar please

```
self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Studies" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSError *error;
self.StudiessList = [_context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [sort descriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your fetch request. See NSSortDescriptor.